# Противоречивый образ титана в мифологии и действительности

Tags: лексика, литература

***Титаны Возрождения!*** Ренессансный тип личности. Пушкин — титан русской поэзии.

Но есть же еще ***Титан Прометей***, прикованный к скале. Почему **Зевс победил** Прометея?

**В мифологии:** Титаны — архаические боги, олицетворявшие **стихии природы** со всеми её катастрофами. **Они не ведают разумности,** упорядоченности и меры, их орудие — грубая сила. Поэтому они не слушают советов Прометея и Фемиды, чтобы хитростью поладить с Зевсом.

**А это уже современность:**

Камерамен титан — это **профессионал**, специализирующийся на освещении событий, съемке и создании качественного видеоматериала. Они играют важную роль в передаче важных событий миру и являются ключевыми служителями журналистики и массовой информации. Будучи экспертами в своей области, камерамены справляются **с самыми сложными задачами,** помогая нам увидеть и понять **наиболее значимые моменты.**

**Так как надо относиться к титанам? Осторожно?**

**Приложение**

Стихотворение А.С. Пушкина, датированное его двадцать девятым днём рождения, 26 мая 1828 года.

```
 Дар напрасный, дар случайный,

 Жизнь, зачем ты мне дана?

 Иль зачем судьбою тайной

 Ты на казнь осуждена?

 Кто меня враждебной властью

 Из ничтожества воззвал,

 Душу мне наполнил страстью,

 Ум сомненьем взволновал?. .

 Цели нет передо мною:

 Сердце пусто, празден ум,

 И томит меня тоскою

 Однозвучный жизни шум.
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149461/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.